# How can I address JSON properties with complex names in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, json

Given a JSON object such as:

```
{
    "@abc.def":"foo"
}
```

How do you address a property named like that?

e.g. this doesn't work

```
var x = obj.@abc.def
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As `@abc.def` is not a valid JavaScript identifier, accessing a property with this name must use [bracket notation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Property_Accessors).

The working code would be:
`var x = obj['@abc.def']`

Answer (score 1):

It will be `obj["@abc.def"]` in your code.

Answer (score 0):

You can use: `var x = obj["@abc.def"]`.
Of course, I suppose that `obj` is defined as: `var obj = { "@abc.def":"foo" }`.